# Locomotive Scroll в next.js проблема при загрузке страницы при обратном скроле

Tags: reactjs, прокрутка, nextjs

Всем привет, проблема такая. использую Locomotive Scroll в своем проекте Next.js. Когда присходит прокрутка страницы вниз, все отлично работает, но когда я возвращаюсь обратно, все как будто заново подгружается, и не всегда сразу отображается, бывает к середине видимого экрана прокрутки.

Answer (score 0):

из-за того что переиспользовал один и тот же компонент несколько раз подряд, поэтому и выдавал такую ошибку